# CMD Window Quickly Opens and Closes

Tags: windows, windows-10, cmd.exe, scheduled-tasks

I have noticed lately that in specific intervals, there is some program that is automatically running – I can tell that because a CMD window quickly opens and quits. It even minimizes games, which is annoying. Unfortunately, I can't discover which program automatically runs at this specific minute (38th and sometimes 44th minute of every hour). I checked processes and all processes by the ProcessMonitor application, but there are so many items I cannot figure out which program it could be. I am using Windows 10 Professional.

Comment: Check the Task Scheduler.

Comment: Use the Process Tree toolbar button in Process Monitor for a hierarchical view of all the processes.

Comment: The reason the Windows tag was added back is because the question applies to all versions even if the author is using Windows 10

Answer (score 2):

A few ideas:

## Slow motion

Try running a screen recorder (ex: built-in 'Steps Recorder' or 'CamStudio') during the time the command is known to run. Once complete you can step through the video to review the results.

## Process activity

Use the Sysinternals ProcMon or ProcExp utilities to review any cmd.exe

## Event log

Use the windows Event Viewer to view the system and application logs around the time the command runs.

## File system modifications

Do a system wide search for files modified in the last minute immediately after the command runs.

Comment: I try CamStudio (or similar app).

Answer (score 2):

Look in your Task Scheduler. 
On my Windows 7 system, I can get there
with “Start” → “All Programs” → “Accessories” → “System Tools”,
or by clicking on “Start”, typing “sched”,
and clicking on “Task Scheduler” when it appears. 
The second method will probably work for just about everyone.

When I do that, I see this:
[image: Task Scheduler window (small, cropped view)]
[<sup>(Click for larger image.)</sup>](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9inBL.png)

which is not too surprising, since my machine is a Dell. 
And, yes, I get a CMD-like window popping up in my face at 7:19 PM
every Tuesday, and disappearing before I can read it.

The things in the left pane
(click on the above image to see a larger image) that look like folders,
are folders. 
You may need to search through them to find what you’re looking for.

To edit a scheduled task,
right-click and select “Properties” (or one of the other options).

Comment: I forget to mention I already check this and there is not any program which could do this. (I tried to disable many services, but it does not help).